# Multi-File Assembly for ASP.NET (MVC) Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I want to adjust my MVC project, so that I can [build a multi-file assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe.aspx).  My intent, as a proof of concept, is to make the root web.config a part of the MVC assembly.  The rationale for doing so, would be to prevent tampering with the web.config file.

The presumed "I must modify" section of the MVC project is here:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

I don't recall how I can "influence" the imports.  For example, is there a property I can set to make the `csc` build step produce modules instead of assemblies?  And even if I achieved that, I need a list (viz. itemGroup) of the resulting module(s), so that I can feed that into the linker (either "csc /out" or "al /out /target").

Anyone done this before?  Pointers?

Comment: I don't see how netmodules will prevent web.config tampering?

Comment: Why store anything in the web.config if you don't want people to change it?  Why not just hardcode your own static class with the values you want?

Comment: @vcsjones: .net/fusion will prevent a (strong named) assembly from loading which has a modified hash; the hash is composed of all file-parts.

Comment: @Josh: Keeping everything in web.config retains standard programming model and "developer experience".  The non-tampering is for the fielded application.

Answer (score 1):

You can split out all of the data from the web.config into a seperate data file that can be encrypted.  Your web.config would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebSectionGroup, System.Web, Version=%ASSEMBLY_VERSION%, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=%MICROSOFT_PUBLICKEY%">
            <section name="authentication" type="System.Web.Configuration.AuthenticationSection, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <!-- Other system.web sections -->
        </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web configSource="OtherFile.config"/>
</configuration>
```

You could then Encrypt the "Other File" so it can't be tampered with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
<system.web>   
     <machineKey validationKey="D61B3C89CB33A2F1422FF158AFF7320E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D94018787EF42682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE"
       decryptionKey="FBF50941F22D6A3B229EA593F24C41203DA6837F1122EF17" />
   </system.web>
```

See MS documentation on Encrypting Section data:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx

It wouldn't be embedded, but obfuscated beyond human readable text.
Hope that helps!